# Listener is not calling for facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook, listener

I am **integrating** facebook sdk in my android application with single signon.

Facebook application if installed called but the problem is after authorization my `listener` does not called.

Here is my code.

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream", "user_photos", "email" }, 20003, 
            createAuthorizeFacebookDialogListener(facebook,2003));
```

and here is the `listener`

```
private DialogListener createAuthorizeFacebookDialogListener(final Facebook facebook, final int facebookAuthorizeCompleteId)
    {
        DialogListener listener = new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values)
            {
                saveCredentials(facebook);
                showToast("Authentication with Facebook");
                if (messageToPost != null) {
                    postToWall(messageToPost);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
            {
                showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
                finish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e)
            {
                showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
                finish();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
                finish();
            }
        };
        return listener;
    }
```

control does not come back after authorizing the application.

Please help me in this.

Comment: maybe there is an error in your saveCredentials? As this looks ok

Comment: control does not comes inside the listener at all.

Comment: Are you calling authorizeCallback() from your activity's onActivityResult?